# Can someone walk me through this wolframalpha solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, integers, wolfram-alpha

Given
$$x = (625/50)a-(100/50)$$
$$x = (214/60)b-(110/60)$$

The following `integer solution` was provided by [a wolframalpha widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%2F%2Fmath:x%20%3D%20(625%2F50)a-(100%2F50)%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:x%20%3D%20(214%2F60)b-(110%2F60)%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:%2F%2F%5D):

$$a = 214n+10$$
$$b = 750n+35$$
$$x=2675n+123$$

I am **very interested** in how the *10*, *35*, and *123* were determined here because they are the actual values of a, b and x and I didn't think they couldn't be solved.

This is the only algebra solver I found that produces these values and unfortunately they don't show a step by step here.

Can anyone walk me through the steps that produce this solution? [Here is a link to the wolframalpha widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%2F%2Fmath:x%20%3D%20(625%2F50)a-(100%2F50)%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:x%20%3D%20(214%2F60)b-(110%2F60)%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:%2F%2F%5D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram also gives a solution in the reals which is equivalent to the following:
$$b = \frac{5(75 a - 1)}{107}\\x = \frac{25 a-4}{2}$$
This is what you get if you consider $a$ a constant and solve for the two remaining variables $x$ and $b$ in terms of $a$.

We want everything to be integers. This is easy for second equation - for $x$ to be an integer, we need $a$ to be an even number.

The first equation is trickier - for $b$ to be an integer, we need $75 a - 1$ to be a multiple of $107$. By trying various small numbers for $a$, you will find soon enough that $a=10$ works: $75*10-1 = 749 = 7*107$. Once you have that solution, then you also know that $a=10+107$ will work to make $b$ an integer, as will $a=10+2*107$, or in fact $a=10+107k$ for any integer $k$.

Combining this with the fact that $a$ must be even, you get that $k$ is even, so $a=214n+10$. The expressions for $b$ and $x$ then follow by substituting this into the equations.

I skipped a lot of details in the above to give you the overall flow of the reasoning. Those details have to do with [Modular Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Here is just a short overview of those details, with links for you to find out more.

1)  When is $75 a - 1$ a multiple of $107$?

This is just the modular equation $75a-1\equiv0 \mod 107$, or $a\equiv 75^{-1} \mod 107$. To solve it, you need to find the inverse of $75$ modulo $107$, which exists because $75$ and $107$ are coprime. This is done using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which gives the result that $10*75-7*107=1$, so $10$ and $75$ are inverses modulo $107$.

2) How do you combine the restrictions on $a$ imposed by the two equations?

In this case the second equation imposed a simple restriction, that $a$ is even. We actually have the two modular equations:
$$a \equiv 10 \mod 107\\a \equiv 0 \mod 2$$
With different numbers it would have been a bit trickier to combine them into a single restriction, and we would have had to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I'm actually working on a software project that incorporates this math in a portion of it's logic. Been quite the adventure.

So I was able to reproduce, in code, the target values using an Extended Euclid algo script, which is great! Any minor adjustment to the inputs still produce the results I would expect. However, when using much larger numbers, the results are no longer accurate. Could you take a look at these results and spot any reasons or errors?

Comment: `x = (30639/6190)a-(4605/6190)` and `x = (13743/5520)b-(8190/5520)`, when plugged into the wolframalpha widget do produce the results I would expect so I can assume the equations are valid for this. The widget gives a real solution equivelent to `b = (1879192a + 280850)/945213`. When `1879192` and `945213` are plugged into an Extended Euclid Calculator however, the results are not even close. Any insight would be helpful!
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+(30639%2F6190)a-(4605%2F6190),x+%3D+(13743%2F5520)b-(8190%2F5520)

Comment: In this case I secretly know that `a = 25` and as you describe, `(25 * 1879192) + 280850` should produce a multiple of `945213`, but it doesn't. I suspect the equation wasn't simplified enough? You factored out `5` in your example. I don't think this example can be factored any more. They are co-prime, so no issues there.

Comment: @Levitikon  $25*1879192+280850 = 47260650 = 50*945213$ so it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting,

$$\frac{25}{2}a-2-\frac{107}{30}b+\frac{11}{6}=0$$

Get rid of the denominators

$$15\cdot25a-60-214b+55=0$$

$$375a-214b-5=0$$
It's now obvious that it's a usual [linear diophantine equation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/). <-- As you can see here, it can be solved with the extended Euclidean algorithm.